# Unable to display name of every row in heatmap

Tags: javascript

I am creating a heat map using html, and JavaScript.
My x axis is having 24 hours, and y axis is having all the days of year, 365 days.

But on the y axis I am unable to display the name of every date. It is displaying the name with some step size. Can anyone solve this?

Comment: which code/framework are you using to create/display your heatmap? can you share the relevant code with us, so we can see where the problem might be?

Comment: iam doing it in html file and using javascript. for data i have used json dictionary

Comment: how to send my code here, i am not finding

Comment: below your question on the left side there is a link `Edit`, after a click you can edit the text of your question. When you inserted your code, highlight it and click the `{}` button to format it, then save your edit.